# Add a parameterized list of security groups to another security group's ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'd like to create a CloudFormation template that creates a security group resource that allows ingress from a variable list of other security groups. The template would take a parameter of type `List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>`. I'll name this parameter `SourceSecurityGroupIds` for this example. Then, it would create a security group resource using something like:

```
{
    "LogServerSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "XYZ security group",
            "VpcId": "vpc-abcxyz",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": 1234,
                    "ToPort": 1234,
                    "SourceSecurityGroupId": { "Ref": "SourceSecurityGroupIds" }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, the `SourceSecurityGroupId` property of `SecurityGroupIngress` doesn't take a list. Is there a way to make this work?

## Update - Feb 27, 2019

In retrospect, the correct way to do this is to create a `LogSourceSecurityGroup`, and allow ingress only from that security group. Then, add that security group to any EC2 instance, etc that should be able to communicate with the log server.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late so you already figure it out, but I just run into this same issue and I was able to fix it. You need to create a "Security Group Ingress" resource that will add the rule to an existing security group, so it would be like:

```
{
    "LogServerSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "XYZ security group",
            "VpcId": "vpc-abcxyz"
        }
    },
    "LogServerSecurityGroupIngress" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
        "Properties" : { 
            "GroupId" : {"Ref" : "LogServerSecurityGroup"},
            "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
            "FromPort" : "1234",
            "ToPort" : "1234",
            "SourceSecurityGroupId" : {"Ref" : "SourceSecurityGroupIds"}
        }

   }
}
```

You can find more information here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-groupid

Answer (score -1):

`SecurityGroupIngress` parameter above is an array/list. So, define multiple ingress rules there.

e.g:

```
  "SecurityGroupIngress": [
    {
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "FromPort": 1234,
      "ToPort": 1234,
      "SourceSecurityGroupId": "SG-12345"
    },
    {
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "FromPort": 1234,
      "ToPort": 1234,
      "SourceSecurityGroupId": "SG-abcde"
    },
    {
      "IpProtocol": "tcp",
      "FromPort": 1234,
      "ToPort": 1234,
      "SourceSecurityGroupId": "SG-54321"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Your solution does not use a variable list of security groups specified by a parameter.

Comment: @Sean, it doesn't work that way. [Read the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-rule-sourcesecuritygroupid)