# How to add 'Always Required' Values to a CommaDelimitedList

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm attempting to create an [IAM Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html) for limiting access to selected S3 Buckets. There are some default `S3 Bucket ARNs`, that must **always** be present, the template operator is allowed to add a list of additional `Bucket ARNs` to grant access to, through a [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

In my template the `BucketARNs` [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html), allows the operator to specify a list of ARN that is not limited in length.

```
  BucketARNs:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: 'Add the ARN of S3 Buckets that the Get* and List*
      access to. When specifying a Bucket 2 values should be supplied one for the
      bucket and for objects within that bucket, for example: arn:aws:s3:::MyContentBucket,arn:aws:s3:::MyContentBucket/*  .
      This defaults to all buckets.'
    Default: arn:aws:s3:::*, arn:aws:s3:::*/*
```

The policy document that uses this [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) looks like

```
PolicyDocument:
  Version: '2012-10-17'
  Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
    - s3:Get*
    - s3:List*
    Resource:
      !Ref BucketARNs
```

I want to do is ensure that, for example

```
arn:aws:s3:::MyMustHaveBucket,
arn:aws:s3:::MyMustHaveBucket/*
```

ARNs are **always** present in the list of `BucketARNs`. The `Default` in the [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) can be removed by the operator - Is the only solution to add them as `Default` values and add information in the [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) `Description` warning users not to remove the required ARNs? Which like it could be easily broken.

Does anyone know a way of ensuring I always have these available? considering the list of BucketARNs specified via the [Parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) is variable?

Ideally, I'd like a list concatenation function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can use `AllowedPattern` on a `String` Parameter along with a `Default` value to ensure that the provided default is always included in the supplied parameter, then use `Fn::Split` to resolve the parameter into an array when used in your template:

   ```
   Parameters:
     BucketARNs:
       Type: String
       Default: arn:aws:s3:::*, arn:aws:s3:::*/*
       AllowedPattern: arn:aws:s3:::\*, arn:aws:s3:::\*\/\*.*
   Resources:
     Dummy:
       Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
   Outputs:
     Result:
       Value: !Join [',', !Split [',', !Ref BucketARNs]]
   ```
2. You can use [`Fn::Split`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html) along with [`Fn::Sub`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) and `Fn::Join` to append your fixed values to a user-supplied Parameter:

   ```
   Parameters:
     BucketARNs:
       Type: CommaDelimitedList
   Resources:
     Dummy:
       Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
   Outputs:
     Result:
       Value: !Join [',', !Split [',', !Sub [
         "arn:aws:s3:::*,arn:aws:s3:::*/*,${Buckets}",
         {Buckets: !Join [',', !Ref BucketARNs]}
       ]]]
   ```

The final `!Join` in the above examples are only to output the Array in the Stack Output, they're not needed when using the parameters in an actual property input to your template.

Comment: I really like this. I think your solution would also work for this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082228/add-a-parameterized-list-of-security-groups-to-another-security-groups-ingress?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use FN::join to concatenate the constants with the parameters